# Find "Smoke" settings under Domain tab

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I am following some basic tutorials of smoke simulations. And I always can't find the settings tab "smoke" under the smoke domain settings. I jumped through some tutorials to see if I am just using another blender version (2.92) but I always have the same problem. Also, the smoke sim looks a behaves different. It feels like they have different preset settings, but the most looks the same. I am also using mantaflow as everyone else. I am very new to smoke sims but have a good understanding of blender. I hope someone can explain. Thank you in advance

Here is a picture of the smoke sim of my desktop:

´[image]

And here is an example of a tutorial file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that you are looking for is now called GAS

[image]